# C : Counting Each Character And Word In a Texf File to Dynamic Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, file, dynamic

For example I have a text file includes "I'm having great day!", I want to count each character and word in this file.
in the example "there are 3 a, 1 m" etc.

I'm new at C and know how to open a file, how can find a specific char or word in file but couldn't figure this out. Can you help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to learn is how to open and process a file one character at a time. You can do this with a program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Must provide one argument, the file to process.

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: myprog <inputFileName>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Try to open the file.

    FILE *inFile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (inFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Process file, character by character, until finished.

    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF) {
        putchar(ch);  // <accumulate>
    }

    // Close file and exit.

    fclose(inFile);
    // <output>
    return 0;
}
```

Then it's a matter of changing the `putchar` call into whatever you need to do (accumulating character counts) and outputting that information before you exit from the `main` function.

Comment: actually try to make it with 2 for loops but fscanf gets just first word, so dont know how to get all content as string (searched for this already) and split it with strtok();... actually searched a lot but still couldnt fidn the way...